# I have problems with right test variable with mark attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I want to test variable, if its possible, I want it with attribute. So I have a XML:

```
<tr class="alt-row">
<td class="column-country">American Samoa <span class="type">(Mobile)</span></td>
<td class="column-rate">0.500</td>
<td class="column-vat">0.575</td>
</tr>
<tr class="">
<td class="column-country">Andorra <span class="type">(Landline)</span> <span class="free">FREE*</span> <span class="superdeal">SuperDeal!**</span></td>
<td class="column-rate">FREE*</td>
<td class="column-vat">FREE*</td>
</tr>
```

And when td class = "column-rate" is FREE*, I need to put number 0, otherwise its normal rate. If its possible I want it with attribute / free = 1, rate = 0. or free = 0, rate = 0.500. Or in normal way :D... without free... So if column contains from FREE*, put number 0. END.

I try this:

```
<country>
  <xsl:variable name="country" select="normalize-space(xhtml:td[@class='column-country'])"/>

  <xsl:attribute name="name">
     <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($country, '('))"/>       
  </xsl:attribute>


  <rate>
    <xsl:variable name="type1" select="normalize-space(xhtml:td[@class = 'column-country']/xhtml:span)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="type" select="translate($type1, '()', '') "/>
    <xsl:variable name="price" select="normalize-space(translate(xhtml:td[@class = 'column-rate'], 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyxABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVVWXYZ()*¢$€', '')) "/>
    <xsl:variable name="cena">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$price != ''">
          <xsl:value-of select="$price"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$VAT"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="cena1" select="normalize-space(substring-before($cena, '(')) "/>
    <xsl:variable name="cena2" select="normalize-space(translate(xhtml:td[@class = 'column-rate'], 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyxABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVVWXYZ()*¢$€', '')) "/>


    <xsl:attribute name="type">
      <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>       
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="operator">
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:attribute name="currency">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Currency"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="vat">
      <xsl:value-of select="$VAT"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="unit">
      <xsl:value-of select="$UNIT"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="$cena2"/>
  </rate>    
</country>
```

and my ouput is:

```
   <country name="American Samoa">
      <rate type="Mobile" operator="" currency="EUR" vat="0" unit="minute">0.500</rate>
   </country>
   <country name="Andorra">
      <rate type="Landline" operator="" currency="EUR" vat="0" unit="minute"/>
   </country>
```

but i need that:

```
   <country name="American Samoa">
      <rate type="Mobile" operator="" currency="EUR" vat="0" unit="minute">0.500</rate>
   </country>
   <country name="Andorra">
      <rate type="Landline" operator="" currency="EUR" vat="0" unit="minute"/>0</rate>
   </country>
```

or

```
   <country name="American Samoa">
      <rate type="Mobile" operator="" currency="EUR" vat="0" unit="minute">0.500</rate>
   </country>
   <country name="Andorra">
      <rate type="Landline" operator="" currency="EUR" vat="0" unit="minute" free="1"/>0</rate>
   </country>
```

But its not work correctly, because when its FREE, the rate is empty.

Comment: Are you sure that this is XSLT code you are using? Usually, a `<param>` tag is not permitted behind a `<variable>` tag, but only at the beginning of a template or at the beginning of a stylesheet. Could you validate your XSLT? A little indentation to make it more readle would be a good idea, too.

Comment: ... its not relevant, but OK... yes I'm sure... but ok i can paste the whole code, to see ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
...
<xsl:variable name="cena">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($price)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$price"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
...
```

Comment: @miroyeah: By accepting this answer you actually change the functionality of your XSLT. user3016153 used a constant value instead of the value of parameter `VAT` which is passed to your XSLT. In my call of your XSLT the value of `VAT` was `'0'` so it yielded the correct result. So, actually @user3016153 both corrected the `test` (in a more elegant way than I did) _AND_ he found a functional error since the value for value added tax can hardly be the default for a missing price. You were lucky since it is usually very difficult for the people at StackOverflow to find _functional_ errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is one definite and one probable error in your XSLT. The definite error is caused by comparing the variable `price` to an empty string. Since the variable is derived from a `translate` function call it is actually containing five spaces (from `FREE*`) since `translate` only replaces each character in the source character string by the corresponding character in the destination character string *with space being the default if the destination string is too short*. So, I would suggest that you change your test to

```
<xsl:when test="normalize-space($price) != ''">
```

However, this done, you will proably (depending on the context) run into the other error by calling `<xsl:apply-templates>`. What do you need this for? I would suggest that that you simply delete it.

Comment: I guess then we will need your stylesheet declaration and the template bracing your code. Otherwise it will be difficult to find an error which might be in your setup.

Comment: The code in the paste bin works for me after removing the `<apply-templates>` call and adding the namespace information to your input. I think the only thing that can still be different in your setup are any default parameters passed to the XSLT processor. Do you set anything explicitly?

Comment: no I think, you do it wrong... it must be some easy way to do it... like always...  with some test, or something...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43326/discussion-between-marcus-rickert-and-miroyeah)