# XSLT: Best Practice in handling nulls and empty string

Tags: xslt

I myself do not know XSLT. Please see my requirements below, I have changed the question format now

Can you please help me with the following points:

1. Following output is required see sample output.
2. SSN / PSN, both may have leading zeroes they should be removed
3. SSN or PSN should be displayed depending if the node has a value
4. If SSN or PSN has the string null it should be suppressed.
5. Address may have null it should be suppressed

Sample Output:

Subject: Item SSN; concat  and

Address:

Source XML File:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <!-- This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database -->
    <bookstore>
      <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
        <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
        <author>
          <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
          <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
          <SSN>0001111</SSN>
          <PSN></PSN>
          <address>null</address>
        </author>
        <price>8.99</price>
      </book>         
</bookstore>
```

Comment: You have exactly the same content inside the `when` and the `otherwise`, so the test is redundant, you could just do away with the `choose` altogether.

Comment: Is `$csmmid` a *numeric* value? IOW, can it contain characters other than digits (not including the case of 'null')?

Comment: Add more of your XSLT stylesheet for better answers.

Comment: Also add the source some of your source document, so that the transformation you want to perform becomes apparent.

Comment: I have now change the question format, I could not include the original xslt as it is a beast. I have re-created the scenario in the sample xml and want your expert advice how this transform should be done using best practices, currently some developer has tons of choose statements all over the place just handle nulls etc

Answer (score 0):

No.1: The required output is not quite clear: what format should it take(XML, HTML, text)?

No.2, 3, and 4: Use  the expression "number(SSN)" as both the test and the result - see a quite similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630832/i-have-problems-with-right-test-variable-with-mark-attribute/20634887#20634887). This is assuming these items are numeric.

No.5: Almost the same thing: test for "address and address != 'null'".

Disclaimer: we only see a very small part of the whole picture. Any advice about strategy is iffy at best in such circumstances.

---

**Added:**

I probably shouldn't be doing this, because it's closer to a tutorial than to an answer. Still, in the spirit of the season...

Given this XML source document:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bookstore>
    <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
        <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
            <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
            <SSN>0001111</SSN>
            <PSN></PSN>
            <address>null</address>
        </author>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>     
    <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="2004" ISBN="9785961401875">
        <title>My Life</title>
        <author>
            <first-name>Bill</first-name>
            <last-name>Clinton</last-name>
            <SSN></SSN>
            <PSN>00022</PSN>
            <address>1600 Pennsylvania Avenue</address>
        </author>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>     
</bookstore>
```

the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/bookstore">
    <html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <h1>Books</h1>
        <hr/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="author"/>
    <hr/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="author">
    <p>
        <xsl:text>Author: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(last-name, ', ', first-name)" />
        <br/>

        <xsl:if test="number(SSN)">
            <xsl:text>SSN: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="number(SSN)" />
            <br/>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="number(PSN)">
            <xsl:text>PSN: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="number(PSN)" />
            <br/>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="address/text() and address!='null'">
            <xsl:text>Address: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="address" />
        </xsl:if>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce this output:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>
<h1>Books</h1>
<hr>
<h3>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</h3>
<p>Author: Franklin, Benjamin<br>SSN: 1111<br></p>
<hr>
<h3>My Life</h3>
<p>Author: Clinton, Bill<br>PSN: 22<br>Address: 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue</p>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

rendered as:

## Books

---

#### The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin

Author: Franklin, Benjamin
SSN: 1111

---

#### My Life

Author: Clinton, Bill
PSN: 22
Address: 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue

---

Comment: Thanks, I am not XSLT literate so please if possible put a sample together so I can see how it should be done.

Comment: Result should be html please.